# Limit of a rational expression involving sinus

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

The task is to find
$$L= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^2 - \frac{n}{\sin(\frac{1}{n})}.$$
For sufficiently large $n$ we have $\sin(\frac{1}{n}) \approx \frac{1}{n}$ so that
$$ L \approx n^2 - \frac{n}{\frac{1}{n}} = n^2 - n^2 = 0, $$
so the limit $L$ is zero. Am I correct?

Comment: No, you just showed the order $n^2$ terms cancel.  Look at more terms from $\sin(\frac1n)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $f(x):=\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x\sin x}=\frac{\sin x-x}{x^2\sin x}$.

By applying L-Hospital's Rule three times, you can see $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=-\frac{1}{6}$.

Hence in your case, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(\frac{1}{n})=-1/6$.

Comment: You can replace $\sin x$ in denominator with $x$ and then just one application of L'Hospital's Rule is sufficient. Repeated application of L'Hospital's Rule is never a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{6 n^3}+\frac{1}{120
   n^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^7}\right)$$ Now long division
$$\frac 1{\sin \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}=n+\frac{1}{6 n}+\frac{7}{360 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$
$$n^2-\frac n{\sin \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}=-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{7}{360 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.